# How do I get rid of a java.lang.NullPointerException error?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I am writing two classes, one for Store, and one Item class for an assignment. I submit it online and it auto-grades according to an unknown tester.

I get the error: java.lang.NullPointerException

I assume it has something to do with returning null, however I was told to return null in one of the methods. If anyone can teach me what it is and how to fix it, thatd be great!

```
    import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Store {
    private ArrayList<Item> inventory;

    // CONSTRUCTORS

    /*
     * Constructs a store without any items in its inventory.
     */
    public Store() {

    }

    /*
     * Constructs a store by reading items from a given Scanner. The constructor
     * must repeatedly (until item name is *) read items from the given scanner
     * object and add it to its inventory. Here is an example of the data (that
     * has three items) that could be entered for reading from the supplied
     * scanner:
     */
    public Store(Scanner keyboard) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (sc.hasNext()) {
            String s1 = sc.nextLine();

            if (s1.equals("*")) {
                break;
            } else {
                Scanner ls = new Scanner(s1);
                while (ls.hasNext()) {
                    Item item = new Item(ls.next(), ls.nextInt(), ls.nextInt());
                    inventory.add(item);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // MOTHODS

    /*
     * Finds an item by its name if it is part of the store's inventory Name is
     * case-insensitive Returns the Item object corresponding to the given name
     * if the item was found. If an item with the given name was not found, then
     * this method returns null.
     */
    public Item findItem(String name) {
        for (Item item : inventory) {
            if (item.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(name)) {
                return item;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    /*
     * Updates existing item or adds a new item to the inventory. If an item
     * with the same name as the given item already exists in the inventory,
     * then this method updates the quantity for the given item.
     */
    public void add(Item item) {
        for (Item items : inventory) {
            if (items.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(item.getName())) {
                items = item;
            } else {
                inventory.add(item);
            }
        }
    }

    /*
     * Performs operations reflecting selling an item from the store's
     * inventory. If the given item is not found in the inventory then this
     * method prints a message and returns null. If sufficient quantity of item
     * is not available then this method reports an error and returns null.
     * Otherwise (if the item is found and sufficient quantity is present in the
     * inventory) then this method removes the requested quantity from the
     * inventory and returns a new item that contains information about the item
     * purchased.
     */
    public Item sellItem(String name, int quantity) {
        for (Item items : inventory) {
            if (items.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(name)) {
                if (items.getQuantity() >= quantity) { // if name is equal and
                                                        // quantity is enough
                    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
                    Item ret = new Item(name, items.getUnitPrice(), quantity);
                    items.changeQuantity(-1 * (quantity));
                } else {// if name is there, but not enough quantity
                    System.out.println("Error: Found, but not enough quantity");
                    return null;
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println("Error: The item was not found.");
                return null;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    /*
     * Performs operations reflecting return of an item back to the store's
     * inventory. An item can only be returned to inventory if such an item
     * previously existed in the inventory. So, if you try to add bread to the
     * inventory, but there was never bread in the inventory in the first place,
     * then this method will not put the bread back on the shelf. If the given
     * item is not found in the inventory then this method prints a message and
     * returns false indicating the return was not accepted. Otherwise (if the
     * item is found) this method adds the returned quantity to the appropriate
     * item entry in its inventory and returns true.
     */
    public boolean returnItemToInventory(String name, int quantity) {
        for (Item items : inventory) {
            if (items.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(name)) { // if name exists
                items.changeQuantity(quantity); // adds quantity
                return true;
            } else { // it didnt exist
                System.out.println("ERROR: Never existed.");
                return false;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    /*
     * Returns a String representation of this store, consisting of a list of
     * all the store's inventory, and the net value (in dollars) of the store's
     * inventory. Formatting will be as shown in this example:
     */
    public String toString() {
        String ret = "";
        int re = 0;
        for (Item items : inventory) {
            ret += items.toString();
            re += items.getTotalPrice();
        }
        ret += "Net inventory price: " + re;
        return ret;
    }

}
```

Comment: Do you not get to see the full stack trace, which would show you *which line* is throwing the exception?

Comment: @JonSkeet  I do. Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at Store.add(Store.java:75)
at StoreTester.main(StoreTester.java:9)

Comment: @JustaBreitGuy: Do you expect people to count to 75 for you?

Comment: Take the exact line, the NP occurs log all candidates (or use a debugger).

Comment: As noted by others, you must inspect the variables on the line that throws the NPE as one of them is null, and you're trying to use it. Once you've identified the variable, it's usually easy to figure out why by back tracking in your program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your problem:

```
public void add(Item item) {
    for (Item items : inventory) {
        if (items.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(item.getName())) {
            items = item;
        } else {
            inventory.add(item);
        }
    }
}
```

The first time you call this, `inventory` is still null.

Answer (score 3):

You never initialized `inventory`.

```
public Store() {
    inventory = new ArrayList<Item>();
}
```

There could be other places where an NPE could occur.  Please, next time tell us the exact line in your source where the exception occurs.

Comment: How can `inventory` be initialized in another (unprovided) class if  it's private and you provide no other methods to set it?

Answer (score 2):

After running your code I got this

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at swing7.Store.<init>(Store.java:36)
    at swing7.Store.main(Store.java:145)
```

which shows that `inventory` was clearly never instantiated:

```
private ArrayList<Item> inventory;
```

Easily fixed:

```
inventory = new ArrayList<Item>();
```